# Alertifyjs validation on prompt

Tags: javascript, alertifyjs

I'm using [alertifyjs](http://alertifyjs.com/) that's great but I have a small issue I wish to solve, maybe with your help.

Using the [Prompt Component](http://alertifyjs.com/prompt.html) I would like to force the user to write a "reason" in the input field and to be honest I don't know how to do that...

Actually my code is like that:

```
  alertify.prompt(
        'Warning!',
    'Are you sure you wish to CANCEL the order?',
    'Enter reason please...',
    function (e, reason) {
      // my code on confirm...
    },
    function () {
        return;
    }
  );
```

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation show the following:

```
alertify.prompt(
    'Warning!',
    'Are you sure you wish to CANCEL the order?',
    'Enter reason please...',
    function (e, reason) {
       if( reason == '' ) { 
           e.cancel = true;
       }
      // my code on confirm...
    },
    function () {
        return;
    }
  );
```

http://alertifyjs.com/prompt/onok.html
*To prevent the dialog from closing, either set closeEvent.cancel = true or make your callback return false .*